# Использование элементов Toolbar

Tags: java, android, toolbar

Поставил Toolbar и сделал кнопку "Назад". Не знаю как поставить на нее обработчик.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Добавьте картинку не ссылкой, а картинкой. А дело, видимо, в стилях. Покажите их

Comment: Изменил стиль на:
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"> и сработало. Но теперь цвета по умолчанию изменились. Например, текст раньше был черным, теперь будет белым, фон был белым, теперь черный. Но это уже изменить можно в XML

Comment: Попробуйте `Theme.AppCompat.Light` и/или `colorPrimary` в стилях поменяйте.

Answer (score 2):

Клик обрабатывается в `onOptionsItemSelected(Menu menu)` , который можно переопределить и взяв id элемента на который кликнул пользователь можно легко обработать.

Если что id кнопки назад, если не кастомный, что можно заметить по вашему коду, то он будет `android.R.id.home`, если не совсем точно указал , прошу поправить.

Answer (score 2):

Все верно, обрабатывается в `onOptionsItemSelected`, примерно вот так:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Toast.makeText(this, "home pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```